# how to print all random numbers in the randrange function of python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to explore the randrange function in python. Is there a way I can print all the numbers in the range of randrange() function. for example, if I have the random.randrange(0,3). Then how can I print 0,1,2

Comment: 0 and 3 are known, you you need to infer them from the random sequence?

Comment: Don't use randrange, then, just use `print range(0, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

`random.randrange(start, stop)` is exactly the same as `random.choice(range(start, stop))` 
<sup><sup>(Which is exactly the same as `range(start, stop)[random.randint(0, len(range(start, stop))]`, but that's not needed.)</sup></sup>

Thus, the value that you need to know lies in the function `range()`:

```
range(0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `range()` instead:

```
range(0,3) # gives [0,1,2]
```